# C: Store strings created by getline() in a Linked list?

Tags: c, string, linked-list, grep, getline

I need to do my own implementation of grep in C. I'm using getline() to read from the file (This being specified by the user, if not, it reads from stdin).

```
char* line = NULL; 
size_t size = 0;
int q = 101; //Prime number for Rabin-Karp Algorithm
bool coincidence;
list_t* list = list_create();
while((getline(&line, &size, file)) > 0 && list) {
    list_insert_end(list, line);
    if (list_length(list) > n + 1) list_erase_first(list);
    coincidence = search(string, line, q);
    if (coincidence){
        while (!list_is_empty(list)) printf("%s", (char*) list_erase_first(list));
    }
}
free(line);
```

That's the code I have now. I create a char* line, which will be replaced by the string received by getline(). Then I try to store a copy of it in a list (Or queue), however, whenever I use getline again, all the copies I made will be replaced.
I need to save the copies of the previous n lines before finding a coincidence, and when I do, I have to print them. I thought of using strdup, but it would have the same results.
I thought of using an array, but I couldn't come up with the right implementation, since I cannot store all the lines in memory, so when I reach n + 1 read lines without a coincidence, I have to erase and replace the first one that was stored. A queue or list would make it so much easier, but I'm unable to save the copies of getline properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have stored `line` into the list (as in the list is storing the pointer value), just set `line = NULL;` so that the next time you hit `getline()` a new line will be allocated.